# onDateChange returns null when user types a past date using react-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I'm using `SingleDatePicker` from `react-dates` and it works fine when selecting a date from the datepicker(even a past date), but when the user types a past date the `onDateChange` handler returns null, but when the user types a future date `onDateChange` returns a moment object.

```
      <SingleDatePicker
        date={moment(Date.now())}
        focused={focused}
        displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
        onFocusChange={() => setFocused(!focused)} 
        onDateChange={date => {
          console.log(date);
        }}
      />
```

Here's what i get when typing the current or future date and `null` is when typing a past date.

[image: screenshot from devtools]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select past days, pass in `isOutsideRange={() => false}` prop.

[source](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/1392#issuecomment-429073506)

```
<SingleDatePicker
  date={moment(Date.now())}
  focused={true}
  displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
  onFocusChange={() => true}
  onDateChange={date => {
    console.log(date);
  }}
  isOutsideRange={() => false}
/>
```